# 2つの配列a,b間でaにのみ存在する要素をbに追加したい

Tags: javascript, jquery

Javascriptで2つの配列の要素を比較し、配列間で重複している要素だけを削除し結合したいと思っています。

比較する配列は以下のような形です。

```javascript
var a = new Array("あああ","いいい","ううう","えええ","おおお");
var b = new Array("あああ","いいい","あああ","ううう","えええ","ううう");
```

配列[a]がすべての要素がひとつずつ入った配列、配列[b]はその中の要素が増減した配列になり、
最終的に、以下の値を取得したいと思っています。

```javascript
("あああ","いいい","あああ","ううう","えええ","ううう","おおお");
```

配列[a]と配列[b]を比較し、配列[a]にだけ存在する要素を配列[b]にpush、
配列[b]の中で重複している要素については、削除せずにそのままにしたいのです。
しかも、必ず配列[b]のほうが要素数が多いとも限りません。。。
※（"あああ"）だけという場合もあります。

ごく簡単なscriptなのかもしれないのですが、思うような結果になかなか辿り着けません。
お力をお貸しください。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

あんまり効率とか考えないで、jQueryタグがついてるのでjQueryも使って以下のように書けるんじゃないかと思います。

```
a=jQuery.unique(a.concat(b));//aとbを結合して重複をなくしてaに書き戻す
jQuery.each(a, function(i,v){ if(jQuery.inArray(v, b)==-1) b.push(v);});//aにあってbにないものをプッシュ
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
ご教示いただいたjQueryで値を取得することができました。
こんなにシンプルに実現できるとは、難しく考え過ぎていたようです。
本当にありがとうございました。

Comment: @m.so もし問題が解決したのであれば役に立ったと思われた回答をアクセプト(回答の左の数値部分の下のチェックマークをクリック)して下さい。
そうすることでこの質問が解決済みということになります。

Comment: ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 2):

jQueryが使えるのであれば $.inArray がありますので以下のように書けます。

```
var a = new Array("あああ", "いいい", "ううう", "えええ", "おおお");
var b = new Array("あああ", "いいい", "あああ", "ううう", "えええ", "ううう");
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    // 配列aの要素 a[i] と配列bを比較し、配列bに存在しなかったら a[i] を配列bにpush
    if ($.inArray(a[i], b) < 0) {
        b.push(a[i]);
    }
}
// → ["あああ","いいい","あああ","ううう","えええ","ううう","おおお"];
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
ご教示いただいたjQueryで値を取得することができました。
jQuery.inArray()まで考えが至らず、大変勉強になりました。
本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow に次の Q and A があります。
- Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/

日本語なら こんな記事もあります。
- 配列の重複をはじく、もしくは重複を取り出す http://qiita.com/cocottejs/items/7afe6d5f27ee7c36c61f

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
完全に検索が足りなかったようです。。。
素早く回答いただけて、大変助かりました。
本当にありがとうございました。